# Mathematica & Statistics?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

So, let's say you flip a coin 10 times, and call that 1 "event". If you run, 1,000,000 of these "events", what is the proportion of events that have heads between 0.4 and 0.6? Binomial probability would suggest this to be about 0.65, but my *Mathematica* code is telling me about 0.24

Here's my syntax:

```
X:= RandomInteger[];
experiment[n_]:= Apply[Plus, Table[X, {n}]]/n;
trialheadcount[n_]:= .4 < Apply[Plus, Table[X, {n}]]/n < .6
sample=Table[trialheadcount[10], {1000000}]
Count[sample2,True];
{* 245682 *)
```

Comment: I don't think this is a "trivial syntax error, ..." and I do think the problem and its solution will be of value to others.  The title should be changed to "Statistical simulation of binomial processes" or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are flipping the coin 10 times, `trailheadcount` can assume only the values `Range[0,1,.1]`.  Thus, the expression `.4 < Apply[Plus, Table[X, {n}]]/n < .6` only selects the value `0.5`.  Indeed, the probability of `0.5` is about `0.246`.  Undoubtedly, you meant `.4 <= Apply[Plus, Table[X, {n}]]/n <= .6`, which selects values `{0.4,0.5,0.6}`.  With this substitution, the computed probability is about `0.66`, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

If you just perform the experiment correctly ...

```
Count[Tr /@ RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {1000000, 10}],  Alternatives[4, 5, 6]]
(* 656190 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to exploit the powerful statistical functions in *Mathematica*.

Here's the basic probability of getting between 4 and 6 heads (inclusive) in 10 flips of a fair coin:

```
Probability[4 <= x <= 6, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[10, .5]]

(* 0.65625 *)
```

And here is a plot of that discrete distribution:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[10, .5], x], {x, 10}]
```

[image]

Now, when you perform this 10-flip experiment a million times, you have success 0.65625 of the time, and hence a binomial distribution of such successes:

```
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[10^6, .65625], x],{x, 650000, 660000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Another benefit of this statistical approach is that you can confirm what the mode of the distribution is (the most likely single outcome):

```
FindMaximum[PDF[BinomialDistribution[10^6, .65625], x], {x, 600000, 700000}]

(*
  {0.000839951, {x -> 656250.}}
*)
```

Comment: I don't think this is THE best approach to perform an "experiment".

Comment: If you perform a simulation and get 656190 (as @belisarius did), how do you know if the disagreement of that result with the predicted result can be expected by chance?  Or might it be a mistake in your code?  The principled statistical approach gives you the result of, in essence, $2^{10^6}$ experiments.  You can understand the *variance* (and indeed all moments) of the distribution.  You can immediately answer:  What if we count $3<x<8$?  What's the probability I'll get more than 660000 successes?  It would take centuries to answer that using the simple computational experimental approach.

Comment: I think all your points are valid. I only said that the OP wanted to perform an "experiment", and the least theoretical artifacts you introduce in an experiment, the better (as they may introduce _your_ thinking bias)

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach (assuming fair coin):

```
bd = BernoulliDistribution[0.5];
rv = RandomVariate[bd, {1000000, 10}];
Length@Pick[rv, 4 <= Total@# <= 6 & /@ rv]/1000000.
```

yields: 0.657009